# install/uninstall of windows services during development

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I would like to know if there is an easier way to install or uninstall windows services onto dev or test environments without creating setup packages? I am having issues with uninstalling visual studio packages sometimes (even after stopping the service and closing the service management console before uninstall forcing me to reboot the machine). this issue can be overcome by using tools like InstallShield or WIX to create setup packages, but during development it will be easier if I can install the service (along with all the dependent files) in dev or test environment without creating a setup package.

Comment: I personally write my services so that they can run as either a plain app or a service, as determined by a command line switch. This makes testing, debugging etc. a lot easier.

Comment: Usually the only time that I have problems with uninstalling windows services is when I'm uninstalling with the Service Control Manager still dialog still open. It seems to be a common issue and that has always fixed it for my scenarios. That might help you at certain times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is part of the .net framework.  Now you still need to copy the bin directory to the desired machine and register any COM objects if you are using any.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if the windows service references some dlls of external components, then should I create a folder under "C:\Program files\Company name" with a service name and then copy all the files under the service folder before running InstallUtil?

Comment: does the installutil write something to registry? because one annoying issue with installations using visual studio packages is that sometimes they don't get uninstalled properly leaving some traces in the registry and also the service is marked as disabled and the only way to get rid of it is to restart the machine

Comment: You can put the files anywhere you want, but yes, copy all the files then run installutil.  As Adrian said in his answer, after the initial install, you can simply stop the service and just replace the files that have been updated since the last install.

Comment: If you remove the service, you need to restart the machine to install a service with the same name.  For development, just stop the service and replace the files with new ones, don't uninstall and reinstall the service.

Answer (score 1):

If remember right,( no access to my dev machine at the moment). Stop the service - and replace the exes and dlls) restart the service. You can script this. You will need to do an initial install, or use the installutil.exe

I found this much easier that installing and uninstalling, all the time.

Comment: that's cool. so once the service is installed, later on I can just stop the service, replace the files and restart the service and that will work without having to install and uninstall everytime? is that correct?

Comment: thats what i used to do. Even had a bat script to do it in two taps of the keyboard...

Comment: may be I am just repeating what u said, but just double checking if I understood it correctly. I was thinking I need to install, uninstall everytime I want to deploy an updated service

Comment: I posted my comment before I saw your reply to my comment. thanks, that is quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

I find the SC.EXE command to be easy to use during development.  Slap it into a NAnt/BuildBuild/Perl/BAT file and instant light weight automation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I feel this information is highly relevant to anyone struggling with this issue:

The problem comes from a change in the Installer included in Visual Studio.  I think the change occurred between VS2005 and VS2008. Regardless, after the change, to have an update installer work properly without uninstalling the prior product, it was recommended that Services be installed via Custom Actions in the Install, Commit, and Rollback phase, but not the Uninstall phase.  I believe this is because the change caused the Uninstall action to occur after the new version was installed, uninstalling your service upon update.  A Condition of "Not PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" is placed on the 3 Custom Actions and Check For Previous Versions must be TRUE. This results in essentially the same result as copying the files over the old ones (but also retains any other install activity such as registering objects, etc.)

This all works great for updates; a new version will install over an existing version, the service remains registered, all is well.  However, if you uninstall, your service is left registered, and a fresh install will attempt to register it again, resulting in the 1001 error.  I use SC.EXE to delete the service manually when I uninstall to avoid this.  You can have a clean uninstall, but it will break update installs, your choice.